# Complex relationships in Laravel (hasManyThrough through a pivot table)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have four tables.

- `products`
- `skus`
- `sku_attribute`
- `attributes`

Each `product` has many `sku`s. Each `sku` has many `attribute`s. And each `attribute` can have several `sku`s associated with it. `sku_attribute` is a pivot table for the many to many relationship between `sku`s and `attribute`s.

This works fine! But now, how do I get all the `attribute`s associated with a `product`?

The following code worked for me.

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->skus->flatMap(function ($sku) {
        return $sku->attributes;
    });
}
```

But I get an error because this doesn't return a relationship but rather a collection.

I also tried using the [solution found here](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db). But I couldn't get it to work properly because their model is slightly different than mine. (Each product has many skus, not vice versa.)

Another solution was to include a third column on `sku_attribute`s for the `product_id`, but I couldn't find a way to default fill this to `sku->product->id` on the `$sku->attach($attribute_id)` method. Instead I'd have to manually call this every time, like `$sku->attach($attribute_id, ['product_id' => $sku->product->id])`.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: The newest version, 5.7.13

Comment: Is this not working? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Nope. Has Many Through doesn't appear to work when it goes through a pivot table. This is because I have two tables in between, not just one. It goes from Product->Skus->SkuAttributes->Attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me.

```php
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->skus->flatMap(function ($sku) {
        return $sku['attributes'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
public function attributes()
{
    return Attributes::whereIn('id', function($query){
        return $query->whereHas('skuAttributes', function($query) {
            return $query->whereHas('products', function($query) {
                return $query->where('id', $this->id);
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Then on the skuAttributes model create a [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to products.

Comment: I tried something similar but unfortunately whereHas and whereIn don't return relationships which throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for this in Laravel.

I created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

You can use the relationship like this:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Attribute::class, [Sku::class, 'sku_attribute']);
    }
}
```